# Android App: Portrait Phone but landscape camera view

Tags: android, view, camera

I'm new to java and android development. I'm developing an application with a camera view in frameLayout window. My application is designed to be in portrait orientation but the window is in landscape < as shown in picture>.
As u r familiar that default camera view is in landscape so I execute 
**camera.setDisplayOrientation (90);**  to rotate it.

My issue is when image is rotated in portrait view under a landscape window it become distorted (Pinched). can any1 help me resolving this issue, can any1 provide me a solution to trim borders to achieve required ratio.

!Im a new user to stackoverflow so m not allowed to upload an image other wise I can show u.

```
     ___________________________________________
    |____________Notification bar_______________|
    |                                           |
    |   My Application                          |
    |___________________________________________|
    |                                           |
    |                                           |
    |                                           |
    |                                           |
    |                                           |
    |                                           |
    |                                           |
    |         camera View                       |
    |          ____________________             |
    |         |                    |            |
    |         |                    |            |
    |         |                    |            |
    |         |                    |            |
    |         |                    |            |
    |         |____________________|            |
    |                                           |
    |                                           |
    |                                           |
    |                                           |
    |                                           |
    |                                           |
    |                                           |
    |                                           |
    |___________________________________________|
```

Code:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) 
{
        if(preview_running){
        camera.stopPreview();
        preview_running = false;
    }

    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

    List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    int mFrameWidth =  width;
    int mFrameHeight = height;

   {
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) 
        {
            if (Math.abs(size.height - height) < minDiff) 
            {
                mFrameWidth = size.width;
                mFrameHeight = size.height;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - height);
            }
        }
    }
    if( (width*height) != 0){
        parameters.setPreviewSize(mFrameHeight, mFrameWidth);
        System.out.println("TEST 1");
    }

    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    camera.startPreview();

    preview_running = true;
}
```